# How do i get the years between range of years

Tags: php

How do i get the years between range of years

```
$starting_year=2016;
$ending_year=2020;

for ($x = $starting_year; $x < $ending_year; $x++) {
    echo "$x <br />";
}
```

current output

```
2016
2017
2018
2019
```

desired output

```
2017
2018
2019
```

Comment: basic math:  `$x = $starting_year+1;`

Comment: Agree with @rtfm, that's basic math. 2016 + 1 = 2017; 2020 - 1 = 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This -

```
<?php
$starting_year=2016;
$ending_year=2020;

for ($x = $starting_year+1; $x < $ending_year; $x++) {
    echo "$x <br />";
} ?>
```